# Getting csv from table without any grouping SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that contains only two columns say Name, DepartmentId as follows

```
CREATE TABLE #TempDepartment
(
    Name NVARCHAR(50)
    ,DepartmentId INT
)

INSERT INTO #TempDepartment VALUES
    ('ABC',1)
    ,('ABC2',1)
    ,('DEF',2)
    ,('XYZ',3)
```

I am looking to retrieve list of distinct departmentId in comma seperated format. How can I achieve this in SQL? Basically there is no common group item, hence the confusion with either using STUFF or COALESCE.

Expected output is - 1,2,3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query

```
Select Top 1 STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(DepartmentId AS Varchar(20))
       FROM #TempDepartment b   Group By DepartmentId     
       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') CSV
From #TempDepartment
```

**[Fiddle Output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18164)**

**O/P :**

```
+---------+
| CSV     |
+---------|
| 1, 2, 3 |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT DepartmentId 
    FROM #TempDepartment 
)
SELECT TOP (1)
   STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(DepartmentId AS VARCHAR(10)) 
          FROM CTE FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM CTE
```

Should produce the required output:

```
1,2,3
```

Comment: This works too except that the other solution is eliminating the need for CTE. Thanks again.